How do I rework texture?
I found a cool texture pack for Minecraft Java here, but it's outdated. I want to update it to the latest version and make a few changes.
Basically, I want to change a bit so that it looks iron based while keeping the pattern of the attacking indicator (crosshair).
Could someone guide me?
